#  php security for cookies and sessions

Tags: php

Regarding PHP security with cookies and sessions, this is what i have done so far for prevention of attacks.  What have i done incorrectly/unsafely?

login.php

```
 if ($username==$dbusername&&$hashed_password==$dbpassword){

setcookie('username[0]',$username,time()+(60*60*24*365));
setcookie('username[1]',$userid,time()+(60*60*24*365));
setcookie('password',$hashed_password,time()+(60*60*24*365));

if($admin=='1') {
setcookie('username[3]',$admin,time()+(60*60*24*365));  
}
$_SESSION['logged-in']=1;
```

logout.php

```
    $time = time()-(60*60*24*365);
setcookie('username[0]', '',$time);
setcookie('username[1]', '',$time);
setcookie('username[2]', '',$time);
setcookie('username[3]', '',$time);
setcookie('password', '',$time);
unset($_COOKIE['username']); 
unset($_SESSION['logged-in']);
```

I call session_regenerate_id() on everypage, is that correct to stop session fixation/hijacking?

```
<?php session_start(); session_regenerate_id();
```

Here is my PHP.ini what other ways do i provide security for sessions & cookies

```
    session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.user_only_cookies = 1
```

Any examples/impovements welcomed, as i learn better with examples.

Comment: This is what http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for.

Comment: Wow. Never knew about codereview.stackexchange.com. You learn something new every day, huh?

Comment: And no, that code is insecure. Anyone can add the cookie `username[3]=1` and become admin.

Comment: Do i put the flag an account in the database as an admin then? Also how do i prevent the user from adding cookies?  .. i'd prefer a detailed answer but thanks.

Comment: I have a system which basically stores an md5 hash of a random string in a cookie, and links that md5 to a database with all the relevant data. I also regenerate the md5 every time a page is visited. Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: thanks scott, confused when you say your regenerate the md5.  Does that mean you regenerate both the md5 in the cookie and in the database every time a page is visited?

Comment: When I regenerate the md5, I send the new one to the client and update the database, as this keeps both the client and server in sync. It also makes it a lot harder to bruteforce since the md5 regenerates after every page load. A timeout can also help (cookie expiry and auto-deletion from database).

Comment: @ScottS - You are assuming that the other half is keeping up

Comment: @EdHeal if they randomly turn off cookies in the middle of their session... well there's nothing you can do about that. It will mess up any cookie solution. Both halves always keep up for me; I built a CMS and never had any issues since I got the login system working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often regenerating the session-id is done, when changing access priviledges (e.g. after a login).

The password should **not be stored in a cookie** on the client side, not even the hash. It's not even necessary to store it in the session, you use it only to verify the login, and after writing the state to the session, you should forget about the password.

If you want a really safe site, you need a **HTTPS connection** with SSL encryption. Otherwise an attacker can eavesdrop the information sent plaintext, and use the session-id (or whatever you use to authenticate the user) to impersonate the user.

Answer (score 1):

Please Please really Please do not store a password as a cookie. It (the computer) may be in a cafe or elsewhere.

This is a security issue and one open to be broken.

BTW Have a rethink and use a cunning mind as to how a person could break into YOUR system.

Comment: it is a bcrypt password; In the tutorial i used they stored the hashed password in a cookie to compare to the hashed password in the database.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes - Passwords are a one way contract. Just think, imagine that the other person can think and reverse the logic - he is into your account

Comment: @EdHeal Regardless of it being a password, just stealing someone's session cookie is usually enough to gain access.

Comment: I concur - but gaining a password enables one to have access on a different session